# Laravel collection group by

Tags: php, laravel

I have a search function to search for expenses by a certain date, month, string, whatever. It returns a collection:

[image]

So far so good. I can display all returned `Expenses`. Now, what I want to do is, display also a total expense count and total amount, grouped by the `description_id`. If I simply do `$result->groupBy('description_id)`, I just get a set of collections, from which I can display the total count and total amount, but not the name of the description. Example of what I want:

```
Grouped Results (By Expense):

Description Name: <-- Issue displaying this
Total Expenses: 3
Total Amount: 53444
```

The description name can only be obtained via the relation between `Expense` and `Description`. An Expense belongsTo a description.

Is it at all possible to achieve what I want, when working with my collection, or should I perform a seperate query for those results? (undesired)

Comment: I think you should perform this at the query level, as opposed to on the returned collection. You can simply call `DB::select('SUM(expenses) as total_expenses', 'SUM(amount) as total_amount')`..then later, `groupBy('description_name')`

Comment: I will give this a go as it seems like the most obvious thing to do I guess :)

Comment: Maybe you can just eager load description so that when you have the collection, you have a nested object/array of description which can already be accessed (even after groupBy)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you eager-load `description`, then you can group the resulting collection by the nested object of the collection. So you may have:

```
$expenses = Expenses::with('description')->get(); //collection
```

Then group it:

```
$grouped = $expenses->groupBy('description.name'); 
//or
$grouped = $expenses->groupBy('description_id');
```

Then you can use the name of description, accessing it, say we need the first group, and the first expense in the group,

```
$description_name = $grouped
                    ->first() //the first group
                    ->first() //the first expense in group
                    ->description //the description object
                    ->name //the name
```

This is just a little proof that you can get the name of the related model in the collection and use it to solve your question.